# EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH vs GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE

Tags: opengl-es, textures

in OpengGL, do PBuffers maximum size match the textures maxium size?

Comment: It's platform-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH is the maximum width of the pixel buffer, which means the surface on which the graphics are drawn. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is the maximum size of the texture you can use on a 3D face.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: When I read it, I can swear it was different. Anyways, Nicol Bolas is right, it's platform-dependent.